# Can I change default registration link (without htaccess)?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, user-registration, wp-redirect

I'm using url like «wp-login.php?action=register&role=patient» and  «register_form» hook for add extra inputs form which depends on urls like this:

```
add_action('register_form','add_extra_role_fields');

function add_extra_role_fields() {
if (isset($_GET['role'])) { $user_type = $_GET['role']; }

if (isset($user_type) && $user_type == "patient") [...] 
if (isset($user_type) && $user_type == "doctor") [...]
```

**Problem**: Wordpress redirects user after form validation with error to http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register instead of http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&role=patient
and all logic is broken.

**Question**: Can wordpress redirect user to previos url «?action=register&role=doctor» (not default «?action=register») ?

**Solution**: Thank you Jan Fabry :).

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['role']) && ( ($_REQUEST['role'] == 'patient') OR ($_REQUEST['role'] == 'doctor') ) ) {

    add_filter( 'site_url', 'doctor_site_url', 10, 4 ); 

    function doctor_site_url( $url, $path, $scheme, $blog_id ) {
        if ( 'login_post' == $scheme ) {
            $url .= '&role='.$_REQUEST['role'];
            }
        return $url;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To do different registration pages for different user roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep this information in the `$_GET`, you will have to modify [the form's `action` parameter URL](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-login.php#L515). You can do this by hooking into `site_url`:

```
add_filter( 'site_url', 'wpse18418_site_url', 10, 4 );
function wpse18418_site_url( $url, $path, $scheme, $blog_id )
{
    if ( 'login_post' == $scheme ) {
        $url .= '&role=doctor'; // Or do this dynamically
    }
    return $url;
}
```

But instead of always looking in the `$_GET`, it might be a solution to save the `role` field in a hidden field and check `$_REQUEST` instead - it will contain both `$_GET` and `$_POST`.